# What's the Gibbs-Duhem equation for a rubber band?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Consider a rubber band of length $L$ held at tension $f$. For displacements between equilibrium states

$dE=TdS+fdL+\mu dn$

$\mu$ is the chemical potential of a rubber band and n is the mass or mole number

I star using Euler's Theorem:

$f(x_1,\dotso, x_n)=\sum^n_{i=1} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)_{x_j}x_i$

where $f(x_1,\dotso, x_n)=E(S,\vec{X})$ then

$E(S,\vec{X})=\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right)_{\vec{X}}S+\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{X}}\right)_S\vec{X}$

where:

$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right)_{\vec{X}}=T$

$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{X}}\right)_S=\vec{f}$

then

$E(S,\vec{X})=TS+\vec{f}\vec{X}$

here's my question, what's next?, I want to use de Legendre transform in $\vec{f}\vec{X}$  in such a way that I get $\vec{f}\vec{X}=fdL+\mu dn$

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Just to write the relevant Gibbs-Duhem relation? Or do you want to calculate anything meaningful?

Comment: @ArturodonJuan I want to calculate something meaningful

Comment: What do you want to calculate?

Comment: @ArturodonJuan but I don't know if the Gibbs-Duhem equation rubber have a meaning more important than just the relation.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan the Gibbs-Duhem equation for a rubber band

Comment: I mean, besides the Gibbs-Duhem relation, what meaningful physical quantity would you like to calculate?

Comment: @ArturodonJuan I think I expressed myself wrong, when I referred to a more meaningful meaning I meant what am I doing physically by obtaining the Legendre transform of $\vec{f}\vec{X}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant Gibbs-Duhem relation arises from subtracting thermodynamic differential relation from the Euler equation. Let's consider a 1-dimensional rubber-band for simplicity (so no vector signs). Also, there's no change of mass or particle number so I'll ignore the chemical potential $\mu$.

$$dE = TdS+fdL\tag{1}$$

$$E(S,L)=TS+fL\implies dE=TdS+SdT+fdL+Ldf \tag{2}$$

Subtracting these two gives

$$\boxed{SdT+Ldf=0}$$

If we now regard independent variables to be $L$ and $T$ (as it might be in an experimental setting):
$$\begin{align}
S(L,T)dT+Ldf(L,T)&=S(L,T)dT+L\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial L}dL +\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}dT \right]\\
&=\left(S+L\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}\right)dT+\left(L\frac{\partial f}{\partial L}\right)dL \\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Now if you want to calculate how much hotter $dT$ a rubber band will get after you stretch it by $dL$.

$$\begin{align}
dT=-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial L}}{s+\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}} dL
\end{align}$$

Where $s\equiv S/L$ is the entropy per unit length.